# Run-time error using variant array in Excel 2010 VBA

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

G'day,

I've searched high and low for the solution to this issue, so hopefully someone here will know what's going on!

The code I've got so far is below. My understanding is that I need to define i and n as Long, as they use the array variant? At the moment, I'm get the "Run-time error '1004': Application-defined or object-defined error" error after the line:

```
If Cells(i, m) < Cells(i, (m-1)) Then
```

I've tried replacing the i and m variables with integers, purely for testing purposes, but the problem persists. Knowing me, I've indented something incorrectly :|

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub Show_Arrows()

Dim i As Integer
Dim n As Integer
Dim m As Integer

Dim Increasing() As Variant
Dim Decreasing() As Variant

Decreasing = Array(10, 11, 16, 17, 18, 19)

Increasing = Array(12, 13, 22, 25, 26, 31, 32, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 44, 45, 46, 47, 50, 51, 52, 55, 58)

m = (Month(Date) - 4)

For i = LBound(Decreasing) To UBound(Decreasing)
    Cells(i, 16).Select
    If Cells(i, m) < Cells(i, (m - 1)) Then
        ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert("C:\Users\jamie.rosssmith\Documents\Visual Basic Programming\Arrows - Vanessa\Green.png").Select
    ElseIf Cells(i, m) > Cells(i, (m - 1)) Then
        ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert("C:\Users\jamie.rosssmith\Documents\Visual Basic Programming\Arrows - Vanessa\Red.png").Select
    End If
Next

For n = LBound(Increasing) To UBound(Increasing)
    Cells(n, 16).Select
    If Cells(n, m) > Cells(n, (m - 1)) Then
        ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert("C:\Users\jamie.rosssmith\Documents\Visual Basic     Programming\Arrows - Vanessa\Green.png").Select
    ElseIf Cells(n, m) < Cells(n, (m - 1)) Then
        ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert("C:\Users\jamie.rosssmith\Documents\Visual Basic Programming\Arrows - Vanessa\Red.png").Select
    End If
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: I'm not sure how you even get to that line as, unless you've specified otherwise, `i` will be equal to 0, so `Cells(i, 16)` will yield a `1004` error. One thing to consider is that you are declaring `Increasing` and `Decreasing` as arrays of `Variants`, when you really want them to just be `Variants`. And, just out of curiosity, what's your plan for avoiding runtime errors the first four months of the year :) ?

Comment: i starts at the Lower Bound of Decreasing, which in this case is 10, so it shouldn't read as 0? I hadn't thought as far ahead as the first four months of the year haha! I'm adapting an existing spreadsheet for a colleague, and she's up to September, which is in column F...

Comment: Lbound(Decreasing) is 0. Decreasing(0) is 10. You should do some reading on this. It will pay off.

Answer (score 0):

LBound(Decreasing) is 0. You can not select cell with zero index. That's why start your For loop from 1 or change your code to avoid rows with 0 index.
Try this code:

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub Show_Arrows()

Dim i As Integer
Dim n As Integer
Dim m As Integer

Dim Increasing() As Variant
Dim Decreasing() As Variant

Decreasing = Array(10, 11, 16, 17, 18, 19)

Increasing = Array(12, 13, 22, 25, 26, 31, 32, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 44, 45, 46, 47, 50, 51, 52, 55, 58)

m = (Month(Date) - 4)

For i = 1 To UBound(Decreasing) + 1
    Cells(Decreasing(i - 1), 16).Select
    If Cells(Decreasing(i - 1), m) < Cells(Decreasing(i - 1), (m - 1)) Then
        ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert("C:\Users\jamie.rosssmith\Documents\Visual Basic Programming\Arrows - Vanessa\Green.png").Select
    ElseIf Cells(Decreasing(i - 1), m) > Cells(Decreasing(i - 1), (m - 1)) Then
        ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert("C:\Users\jamie.rosssmith\Documents\Visual Basic Programming\Arrows - Vanessa\Red.png").Select
    End If
Next

For n = 1 To UBound(Increasing) + 1
    Cells(Increasing(n - 1), 16).Select
    If Cells(Increasing(n - 1), m) > Cells(Increasing(n - 1), (m - 1)) Then
        ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert("C:\Users\jamie.rosssmith\Documents\Visual Basic Programming\Arrows - Vanessa\Green.png").Select
    ElseIf Cells(Increasing(n - 1), m) < Cells(Increasing(n - 1), (m - 1)) Then
        ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert("C:\Users\jamie.rosssmith\Documents\Visual Basic Programming\Arrows - Vanessa\Red.png").Select
    End If
Next


End Sub
```

Comment: My understanding was that LBound(Decreasing) is 10, as that's the lowest number in the array? I've never used arrays in VB before, so my understanding may be completely off...

Comment: It seems my understanding was off. Are the bounds referring to the contents of the array, rather than their values? Ie. Decreasing(0) = 10, Decreasing(1) = 11 etc? If that's the case, then I can see why I'm getting the error. Is there a better way of achieving what I'm after? Thanks!

Comment: Yes, you are right Decreasing(0) = 10, Decreasing(1) = 11. I can not see where you are using your array values. So you can just use for i = 1 to 6. Correct me if I misunderstood you.

Comment: No you are completely right, thanks for posting the corrected code! Your code generates the required images perfectly, but as @goKart claimed below, the images aren't imported into the desired cells. They appear to be in the same column, but their vertical spacing seems to increase down the page.

Answer (score 0):

Unless specified by you an array index starts at zero.  To ensure it starts at 1 add the Option Base 1 statement underneath Option Explicit.

Next, somewhat annoyingly, Excel doesn't understand Cells.  It does understand worksheet.cells or range.cells.  To work with cells declare a worksheet or range object variable and assign it a value.  For example, Dim wks as worksheet.  Set wks = thisworkbook.worksheets("Sheet1").

When you use an array, I would always use Redim statement when initialising it's size.  Your code for one of your arrays is decreasing = array().  Mine would say Redim decreasing() = array().

While you can import a picture using the approach you've coded it is unlikely to end up in the specific cell you desire.

Thus, if you can, reevaluate your approach and consider if there isn't another way to achieve the desired result.

Comment: Thanks for the advice :) You are totally right about importing the image, they aren't in the desired cells at all. Do you know of a better way of doing this? If I remove the array from the code, and just iterate the If Then ElseIf loop over integers (ie. from i = 10 to 20), the images populate the correct cells...